# How do you multiply each digit of a number by different numbers in python?

Tags: python, function, math, numbers, int

I would like to have the user input a 5 digit number and then have a function that has each digit of that number multiplied by different numbers. For example the first digit would always be multiplied by 5, the 2nd by 4, the 3rd by 3, the 4th by 2,and 5th by 1. I am having trouble figuring out how to use each number individually. How do I create a function that does this?

Comment: Stackoverflow works better if you try to solve the problem yourself and then post your code along with any questions you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter a five-digit number: "))
digits = [(n /10**i)%10 for i in range(4,-1,-1)]
multiplicand = [5,4,3,2,1]
result = [d*m for d,m in zip(digits, multiplicand)]

print result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through each digit in the string with a simple for loop.

```
s = '27302'
i = 5
for n in s:
    print(i*int(n))
    i = i - 1
```